# Vue route: Uncaught TypeError: window.Vue.use is not a function

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

in my Laravel project I'm using Vue library and I'm trying to use vue router in my modules, but when I tried import vue router as usually (*see code below*) I got an error in my console: **Uncaught TypeError: window.Vue.use is not a function**

Any ideas how to solve this issue? I have created this module using webpack.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

import App from './App.vue'

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [{
        'path' : '/user/:id/'
    }]
});

new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#play',
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

Comment: your code seems work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but probably it was a fault of my negligence.

The problem was in JS files order while the page was loading up. Still not sure why this happened. I tried to use generated JS file before  tag, but this didn't work, so I just put my JS file right after Vue template container and it started to work (check snippet below). If somebody has any explanation for that, I would be glad to hear that, because now I could call it "magic".

```
<body>
    @yield('after_body_open')

    {{--Header--}}
    <header>
        @include('layouts.top-bar')

        @include('layouts.header')
    </header>

    {{--Page content--}}
    <main>
        @yield('content')
    </main>

    <div id="play"></div>{{--Vue instance--}}
    <script src="{{ asset('js/vue/play.js') }}"></script> **TO HERE**


    {{--Footer--}}
    <footer></footer>

    {{--Notifications block--}}
    <div id="notifications"></div>{{--Vue instance--}}

    {{--Required JS files--}}
    <script src="{{ asset('js/vue/navigation.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/vue/notifications.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/vue/play.js') }}"></script> **FROM HERE**

    @yield('before_body_close')
</body>
```

Answer (score 18):

I think it's an issue with loading/importing Vue in laravel.
Have you tried changing it to the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue'

window.Vue = Vue
Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

You could try `console.log(window.Vue)` to see if Vue gets attached correctly, or if `window.Vue` is undefined. You could also try that like `console.log(Vue)` to see what gets imported.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: Whats the output if you console.log both Import Typs?

Comment: This has made may 25th December a good day to celebrate

Comment: Tried this and it DID work :) I was updating all my npm dependencies, which in some cases were major version changes eg Mix 5 to Mix 6.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update the `script` element that points to the `index.js` according to what was produced after `npm run build` in `index.html`. This was the difference in loading with old webpack and with vite (I had to add `type="module"` so it could work properly).