# Vue 3, Uncaught TypeError: Vue.use is not a function

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, laravel-vue

I am trying to upgrade the Laravel project's frontend into Vue 3 from vue 2.
During the process, I faced one issue

> Uncaught TypeError: Vue.use is not a function

I don't know what the problem is, please help me if you have any ideas.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Vue.use` is no longer supported in Vue3 as `Vue` is no longer a global instance. You have to add the plugins to the app:

```
const app = createApp(MyApp)
app.use(VueRouter)
```

As described here:
https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#a-note-for-plugin-authors

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the Vue import to:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue'
```

See: [Vue route: Uncaught TypeError: window.Vue.use is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807292/vue-route-uncaught-typeerror-window-vue-use-is-not-a-function)