# How do I convert Google Charts and Vuetify from Vue.use to the new implementation?

Tags: vuetify.js

I understand the concept of the new implementation as plugins as per this example: [Vue 3, Uncaught TypeError: Vue.use is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69276676/vue-3-uncaught-typeerror-vue-use-is-not-a-function)
But I'm unsure how to apply it to Google Charts and Vuetify as when I thought I converted it to the example, it says createCharts is not defined.

**vuetify.js**

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
import "material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css";
import * as Vue from "vue";
import "vuetify/styles";
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";
import colors from "vuetify/lib/util/colors";
import VueGoogleCharts from "vue-google-charts";

Vue.use(VueGoogleCharts); //HERE
Vue.use(Vuetify);        //AND HERE

export default createVuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: "md" || "fa",
  },
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        background: colors.blue.accent2, // Not automatically applied
      },
      dark: {
        background: colors.blue, // If not using lighten/darken, use base to return hex
      },
    },
  },
});
```

This is what I tried to convert it to which says create charts is not defined (it may be wrong so do correct me).

const charts = createCharts(MyCharts);
charts.use(VueGoogleCharts);

const vuetify = createVuetify(VuetifyTheme);
vuetify.use(vuetify);

This method is making me think I need to export it here like createVuetify() below that, however, the chart data is in Home.vue so that's not what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vuetify.use(vuetify);` is incorrect.

It should be `app.use(vuetify)` where `app` is your Vue instance created in your **main.js** file which usually looks like:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

If you have your Vuetify plugin created and exported from some other file like you have right now...

```js
export default createVuetify({...})
```

Import it into your main.js and use `app.use()` to register the plugin

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './vuetify.js'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(vuetify)
app.mount('#app')
```

You can chain the `app` methods if you'd like, e.g. `app.use(vuetify).mount('#app')`

The [Vuetify 3 manual install instructions](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#manual-steps) shows the creating and registering of the Vuetify plugin all within main.js

As far as VueGoogleCharts, there is no plugin registration step according to the [installation instructions](https://github.com/devstark-com/vue-google-charts#installation).  Just install with `npm` or `yarn`, and then import directly in a component file with `import { GChart } from 'vue-google-charts'`